# Hyperlink in Datatable with parent id

Tags: lightning-datatable, url, hyperlink

I'm working on a Lightning:Datatable to made a column url type.

I'm unable to see the hyperlink when the reference is parent field API from query. The hyperlink is defaulting to the record Id instead of the Parent record Name.

Apex Class soql:

```
select id,name,parent__c,parent__r.Name from CustomObject__c
```

Cotroller JS:
Column headers:

```
                        var innerHeadersURL = {fieldName: 'parent__r.Name'};
                        var innerHeaders = {label: innerHeadersURL};
                        headers.push({
                            label : 'Parent Name',
                            fieldName : 'linkName',
                            type : 'url',
                            typeAttributes: innerHeaders,
                            target: '_blank'
                        });
```

Data in column:

```
var records =response.getReturnValue();
                records.forEach(function(record) {
                    if(record.Organization__c){            
                        record.linkName = '/'+record.parent__c;
                    }
                });
```

Above code is not giving a clickable label, its giving me clickable Id.
When I replace above code with below line, it gives me clickable link with 'Name' value from soql.

```
var innerHeadersURL = {fieldName: 'Name'};
```

But this woudn''t make the Parent Name on URL,

```
var innerHeadersURL = {fieldName: 'parent__r.Name'};
```

Is it possible to do it or am I missing something here? Please help

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324968/lwc-relationship-fields-in-data-table-flattening-in-lwc/324984#324984 answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use dot (.) notation for fieldName in typeAttributes.

The fieldName property in your header must refer to a field existing in your data (**linkName** does not).

```
var innerHeadersURL = {fieldName: 'whatEverNameWithoutDot'};
                    var innerHeaders = {label: innerHeadersURL};
                    headers.push({
                        label : 'Parent Name',
                        fieldName : 'parent__c',
                        type : 'url',
                        typeAttributes: innerHeaders,
                        target: '_blank'
                    });
```

Then in your JS:

```
var records =response.getReturnValue();
            records.forEach(function(record) {
                if(record.Organization__c){            
                    record.parent__c = '/'+record.parent__c;
                    record.whatEverNameWithoutDot =  record.parent__r.Name;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The base `fieldName` is the link, and you place the label in a `typeAttributes` object with parameter `fieldName`. As the previous answer mentioned, dot notation is not supported in `lightning-datatable`, so the Parent Name will need to either be a field on the object itself (could create a custom formula for `Parent_Name__c`), or you'll need to create a custom property on the Javascript objects that represent the Parent Names.

```
{
    label: 'Parent Name',
    fieldName: 'linkName',
    type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'Parent_Name__c' },
        target: '_blank'
    }
}
```